# Preventing man-in-the-middle attacks with user authentication (Node/Vue/Passport)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, passport.js, vuex

I currently have a webapp I'm writing in Node/Vuejs with Passport handling authentication, and I've run into a problem. I was thinking about how I have authentication currently set up and I realized I had a glaring security hole.

In short, I have my Vuex store hitting a local API endpoint `/api/me`. That endpoint does a simple return of `req.user`. For the sake of brevity, a typical response looks like this:

```
{
  username: 'Bob',
  roles: []  // normal user has no roles,
  email: 'someguy@bob.com'
}
```

My admin route `/admin` has a beforeEnter check, as shown below, that incorporates this check using the Vuex store, so I can have a cached version of user data accessible on the frontend.

```
{
      path: '/admin',
      name: '/admin',
      component: Admin,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        store.dispatch('getMe').then(() => {
          if (store.getters.user.roles && store.getters.user.roles.includes('administrator')) {
            next();
            return;
          }
          next({ path: '/' });
        });
      }
    }
```

Here's the thing though - I realized that someone could easily game the system. In fact, I tried it myself with a test, non-Adminstrator account, and I was able to get in by returning the following from a local server set up for this purpose in Postman:

```
{
  username: 'Super Admin Joe',
  roles: ['administrator']  // normal user has no roles,
  email: 'admin@bob.com'
}
```

And viola! The user now has full access to admin pages.

My question is, how could I prevent against this?

I need to check that the user is authenticated on every page, but a potential attacker could quite easily proxy any request (in this case it's `/api/me`) to make themselves any user they want. They can login normally with their own account, open the Network tab and copy the response payload, then change the user data as they wish. There needs to be some sort of encryption between the frontend and backend when checking a users' logged-in status, I believe.

I tried thinking about how I could prevent this from happening, but anything on my end (server-side, at least) seems useless as any request could easily be redirected to an attacker's local machine.

Any advice on how to "sign" my requests to make sure they aren't being proxied? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you doing client-side validation? Why do you let the client call `/api/me` and act upon the result instead of directly checking `req.user`'s roles in the admin route?

Comment: Can I directly access the user object from the request in the admin route? I didn’t think that was possible.

Comment: I think a better response would have been, I have a cookie being set by Passport called `connect.sid`. How do I use that on the client side to check the admin status of a user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn’t have to be signing the response body of an api request. The typical way to do authentication is to establish a signed session cookie that acts either as an identifier to session information in an external database, or contains session information itself. This cookie should be in the header of your response and passport should give you a way to administer this cookie without you even realizing it.

This way the user can’t tamper with the information sent from the server in a way that’s easy to detect, and since it’s a cookie it will automatically be sent with each request by your browser (although if you’re using some AJAX library you may have to explicitly specify you’d like to send the cookie). What MadEard was referring to in the comment is where the cookie information is able to be accessed using passprt which is the ‘user’ property in the ‘req’ object.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think what I'm having trouble understanding is, how can I verify on the frontend that a user is who they say they are? (Sorry, was not done responding). I can show you my code if that would help. I'm not sure what to do in router.js to lock down the route to administrators only:

https://github.com/gedrick/HydraStream/blob/master/src/router.js
https://github.com/gedrick/HydraStream/blob/master/server.js

Also there is the server so you can see how I serializing/unserializing users.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your github files:

```
server.get("/admin", function(req, res){
    if(req.user && req.user.roles.includes("administrator")){
        //user is an administrator, render the admin panel view
    }else{
        //is not an admin, redirect or send error message
    }
});
```

In every Express route, after authentication with Passport, you have the `req.user` object.

It is established by checking the request cookie `connect.sid`, and checking which session this cookie belongs to on the server.
As such, you can trust that in any Express route, the object `req.user` contains the information relevant to that cookie and you can act upon it.

**A little note**: doing server-side validation should become a reflex for you over time.

The client is meant to display information. If, at any point, you are making the client take any decision that could be a security liability, take a step back and think it again.

Comment: This is very helpful advice, thank you!  (EDIT: yet again, I did not mean to submit yet).

Question though - all of the views (including the admin view) are all handled by Vuejs. Am I supposed to just let the request go through if they are an administrator, and redirect them elsewhere if they are not?

Comment: That's something you can do, yes. The important part is to always check if the user is an admin **on the server**, and do something else if they're not (render another view, redirect somewhere else, send an error message, ...).

Comment: I have seen some examples of people using beforeEnter on their route definitions to do some sort of check, and that seems to me like client-side validation. While I hear you with the "don't do client-side validation" loud and clear, how are they accomplishing this? Changing routes on a single-page app doesn't hit the server and so I'm having trouble understanding how I can validate user status on route changes

Comment: Hi Geddy, I’ll respond to you on this thread because there’s more information to work with and I want to address the single page application comment directly. So if you have a single page application and you’re worried about the client changing data in the browser to access a page he shouldn’t, let’s assess the danger in the scenario. If the user wanders onto a page they shouldn’t, is there data they’ll have access to that they shouldn’t? Well if the backend is securely checking requests it doesn’t matter what’s changed on the client side, the server will fail the request during validation

Comment: Hi @Randy, thanks so much for your response. This all made a lot of sense to me and I realized I'd been approaching this a little misguided. What I'm going to do is only render out the admin section from the server side (so I can securely check that that user is in fact an administrator). On the frontend, the /admin route will not be available. I liked the idea of keeping everything in Vue but communicating user role status through an ajax call just won't cut it in regards to security.

I'd love any more input you have on my new plan for this - thank you again!!

Comment: Also worth mentioning is that ajax calls that I _am_ making on the frontend to get user objects are insignificant, because even if someone were to try to spoof someone else, any calls made back to my server would first be checked for validity. In other words, even if UserA could spoof as UserB, once they tried to, say, add a Twitch follower, my endpoint for adding a Twitch follower would first check that their cookie matched who they said they were. Anyways, thanks so much!